# TestCafe docker - Run tests against app running on hosts localhost

Tags: docker, automated-tests, localhost, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a local dev server running on Mac OS on localhost:3000
I want to be able to run testcafe tests in the docker container, pointing to the app running on the Mac host.

Test code:

```js
fixture('<Page>')
  .page(`localhost:3000/page-test`)
```

I've tried `docker run --network="host"` which should make Mac's localhost accessible, but no success.
Have also read, `host.docker.internal` or `docker.for.mac.localhost` can be used inside the container, but there is no way for me to access, modify the image settings.

Anyone has a similar use case for testcafe docker or knows how to solve this?
Thanks, Radek

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` right in your test code. It does not require image settings modification. Please, keep in mind that this feature was introduced in version 18.03.0-ce and is not available in Docker Toolbox.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your answer!
I have Docker v2.1.3.0, Engine 19.03.2.
I've tried both the hostnames I posted above in the testcode, even before asking here. That didn't work for me.

Comment: I have checked the approach with `.page('host.docker.internal:3000')` on my side and it works on Mac and Win10. Could you please clarify if this url is available in the docker container without the testcafe-hammerhead proxy?

Comment: I was trying different settings also ```--net=host``` etc. Trying now again and I see I actually ignored the real issues. ```host.docker.internal``` works. What I ignored was the error messages after I changed to ```host.docker.internal```. There were errors with waitForReact ```Error in fixture.beforeEach hook - ClientFunction cannot implicitly resolve the test run in context of which it should be executed``` if I removed the hook I got ```Selector cannot implicitly resolve the test run in context of which it should be executed```.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help guys! Im going to try a different approach where the app is running in docker container, not on the localhost.