# Testcafe - how to allow Docker image to reach localhost:3000

Tags: docker, dockerfile, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have running a webapp on my local machine (http:localhost:3000). Im using `testcafe docker image`  to run a container

```
docker run -v ${PWD}/e2e:/tests -it testcafe/testcafe firefox --base-url localhost:3000
```

I'm having this error

```
2) Failed to load the page at "http://localhost:3000/changelog".
Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the
"retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to
execute this test.
You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at
"https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".

      Error details:
      Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "http://localhost:3000/changelog".
```

I tried hardcoding `host.docker.internal:3000/path` in my test, but I dont want to keep that value hardcoded on every test.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006459/testcafe-docker-run-tests-against-app-running-on-hosts-localhost) but he/she endup up creating a container for the webapp, I want to avoid that in order to make the test in local environment more simple

Comment: You can probably use environment variables to make the value dynamic.
Additionally, look into `extra_hosts`, maybe you can set the host to use that way.

Comment: yeah, but I want to know if there is a `docker config` option to solve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your tests on a Linux machine, you can use the [host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) network mode:

```
docker run --network="host" -v ${PWD}/tests:/tests -it testcafe/testcafe firefox ./tests/test.js --base-url localhost:3000
```

Please make sure that the URL in your example is correct (`localhost:300` or `localhost:3000`).

Comment: it didnt work, I run the following command, the webapp is listening port 3000.


**docker run --net=host -v ${PWD}/e2e:/tests -it testcafe/testcafe firefox --base-url localhost:3000**

Comment: im using a mac, idk if that could affect :(

Comment: hmmm seems like this command is only available for linux.
[docker issue](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/238)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that. I think the `--base-url` option is the right way in your case. You can specify relative web page paths in your tests: `docker run --network="host" -v $/tests:/tests -it testcafe/testcafe firefox ./tests/test.js --base-url host.docker.internal:3000`. 

Test: `fixture('My Fixture').page('./path/to/my/page');`